# Is it possible to initialize a member variable in the constructor body, instead of the initializer list?

Tags: c++, ctor-initializer

As you might know,

```
A::A() {
    this->foo = 1;
}
```

Is the same as:

```
A::A() : foo(1) {
    this->foo = 1;
}
```

Which is inefficient because of the double declaration.
The compiler might optimize this, but in my case the class is not a POD.
I must define the member in the constructor body since it can't be compressed into one single line.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: No, you can not *initialize* anything inside the body, only *assign* to it.

Comment: _it can't be compressed into one single line_ write a function

Comment: _"I must define the member in the constructor body since it can't be compressed into one single line."_ This is not true, even if by "define", you mean "assign"

Comment: As for your problem, C++ is a very much free-form programming language. You can split statements, expressions and initializer lists into multiple lines.

Comment: Define/declare. By declare I meant assign, yes.

Comment: _As you might know ... Is the same as ..._ • Well, no, they are not the same.  One has a garbage foo or default constructed foo (depending on what foo is), the other initializes foo.  Then both of them assign to foo, but the second case it is (probably) redundant because foo has already been initialized.

Comment: You don't need the assignment statement in the constructor when you provide an initialization list.

Comment: There are only two places you can *initialize* member variables: 1) in-class initializers. 2) the initialization list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot initialise in the constructor body. It must be done in the mem-initialiser list, or using in-class initialisers (at member declaration). However, nothing prevents you from calling a function (or a lambda) to do the initialisation:

```
A::A() : foo([]() { /* ... */ } ())
{}

// or

A::A() : foo(initFoo())
{}

Foo A::initFoo() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Note: Initialization can also be done with in-class initializers.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Good point, added.